# Advanced CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

A project requires I use CakePHP, and time is short.  All I can find is basic knowledge. It is easy to create multiple database in less than 5 minutes, but after that I'm lost.  Can anyone suggest any book, site, on-line courses, lectures, etc.?

I've read that applications can be built quickly with CakePHP, but the learning curve is steep.  I've learned languages faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best and fasted would be to start with the blog tutorial at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

If you know the basic of MVC and OOP, it would be easy to catch up!

Beyond that point you can look at other peoples code and find out how its done!

The real beauty of CakePHP is the [plugins](http://plugins.cakephp.org).

Answer (score 4):

There is an entire online [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) and [CakePHP API documentation](http://api20.cakephp.org/).

Within the book there many many descriptions, tutorials, examples...etc etc.

The API documents everything in detail, which you can use to further your understanding of any concepts that you don't completely get from the book.

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 3.x documentation here: [CakePHP 3.x book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html).
CakePHP 3 [Review](http://www.toptal.com/cakephp/cakephp-still-fresh-still-hot)

Answer (score 0):

For learning cakephp you can use following link (1) http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html
also for fastest learning you can go for for these links (2) http://cake3.codaxis.com/ and (3) http://demos.developerhints.com/cakephp-cheat-sheet/ but renumber keywords and functions used in above 2nd and 3rd tutorial should be learnt first. Also you keep practicing on your local machine to understand and learn cakephp properly.